change Giga bytes to peta bytes in kusto query?
I have a kusto query that have two columns as shown below & size column is in Giga bytes
Database size
sub1 2541304016738179270
sub2 2539224975164406590
How can I change the Gigabytes into petabytes & create a new column next to "size" using "extend" function or a different way?

Did the below answer worked @HaiY?


I have a kusto query that have two columns as shown below & size column is in Giga bytes. How can I change the Gigabytes into petabytes & create a new column next to "size" using "extend" function or a different way?

As your column is in Gb, You can use below KQL query:
let rithTable=datatable(Database:string, size_gb: long)
[
    "cho1", 2541304016738179270,
    "cho2", 2539224975164406590
];
rithTable
| extend sz_in_pg = size_gb / 1048576.0

Here,
1 TB = 1024 Gb

1 PB = 1024 Tb

So, 1 PB is 1024*1024 = 1048576 GB

Output:

Fiddle.
